# Trimming white space of JSON value during rest call using restassured

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I am using a JSON file and sending that JSON file in a restassured post call .. sample JSON will be like this

```
 {
  "cardNumber": "1234567812345678",
  "fromDate": "2023-09",
  "toDate": "2024-01",
  "pageItems": 10,
  "next": "abcdefgh22122024010000000   1234567833491932459P"
}
```

below code is used to make call

```
Response response = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().urlEncodingEnabled(true)
                      .filter(logFilter)
                      .header("Authorization", token)
                      .header("x-consumer-id",consumerIDHeader)
                      .header("x-correlation-id",correlationIDHeader)
                      .header("Accept-Language","en-CA")
                      .header("Accept","*/*")
                      .header("Cache-Control","no-cache")
                      .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br")
                      .header("Content-Type","application/json")
                      .body(jsonBody)
                      .when()
                      .post(postrcsTransactions);
       System.out.println(response);
```

But in the request body the 3 spaces is trimming as one space, but I need to keep the 3 spaces in the field NEXT to get successful response. Below line shows the request body value for the field NEXT:

```
abcdefgh22122024010000000 1234567833491932459P
```

Comment: Have you consider using another delimeter in the `next` value instead of 3 consecutive whitespace?

Comment: no have not tried it but as per the API requirement its 3 spaces, so thats why i did not try that yet